# How can I solve "ReferenceError: expect is not defined" error message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to test Javascript with mocha. I've this snippet of code:

```
describe('Array', function() {
    describe('indexOf()', function() {
        it("dovrebbe tornare -1 quando l'elemento non è presente", function() {
            expect([1,2,3].indexOf(4)).to.equal(-1)
        })
    })
})
```

and a `test/array.js` file. Mocha was installed with

```
$ npm install -g mocha
```

When I run

```
$ mocha
```

I get this error:

```
$ mocha
․ 

0 passing (5ms)
1 failing

1) Array indexOf() dovrebbe tornare -1 quando l'elemento non è presente:
 ReferenceError: expect is not defined
  at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/simonegentili/Desktop/Javascipt Best Practice/test/array.js:4:4)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:211:32)
  at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:358:10)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:404:12
  at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:284:14)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:293:7
  at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:237:23)
  at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:261:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:317:15)
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Mocha is a test framework; you need to provide your own assertion lib as https://mochajs.org/#assertions states. Thus, `expect` is indeed undefined because you never defined it.

(I recommend [chai](http://chaijs.com/))

```
npm install chai
```

then

(see Amit Choukroune's comment pointing out to actually require chai)

then

```
var expect = chai.expect;
```

Comment: you should use `var expect = require('chai').expect,`

Comment: or `const chai = require('chai')` above it.

Comment: Or `var expect = (typeof require === 'undefined') ? chai.expect : require('chai').expect;` if you wish to run test in mocha on a page in the browser.

Comment: Or `let { expect } = require('chai')`

Answer (score 12):

Try

First, in the terminal

`npm install expect.js`

And in your code:

```
var expect = require('expect');
```

Answer (score 10):

After you install Chai as other posts suggest, with the es6 syntax you should put the import at the top

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case i was using **`JEST Test Cases`**. and i put all **`test.js`** file inside
**`pages/`** folder of next file structure.

So solve my issue by move all **`test.js`** file from **`pages`** folder of **`next file structure`** to inside **`__test__`** folder outside or **`root of the folder`**

Answer (score 3):

```js
let chai = require('chai');

var assert = chai.assert;

describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal(-1, [1, 2, 3].indexOf(4));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to expose `expect` globally, while using `chai`, following should be loaded by means of configuration for your prefered testing library:

```
require('chai/register-assert');  // Using Assert style
require('chai/register-expect');  // Using Expect style
require('chai/register-should');  // Using Should style
```

For example:

`npx mocha --config .mocharc.js *.spec.js`

Comment: And from the CLI just use `mocha --require chai/register-expect`

Answer (score 1):

In my use case, I was running a mocha spec through `karma`. The solution was to install the karma integrations for my test framework libs:

```
npm install karma-mocha --save-dev
npm install karma-sinon-chai --save-dev
```

...and also to add the frameworks to my `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon-chai'],
        files: [
            '.tmp/**/*.spec.js'
        ],
        client: {
            chai: {
                includeStack: true
            },
            mocha: {
                reporter: 'html',
                ui: 'bdd'
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Install Expect.js or Chai.js if you are using Mocha for TDD

So, do `npm install expect` or `npm install chai`

Answer (score 0):

Either add this script tag in html file

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/expect@%3C21/umd/expect.min.js"></script>
```

or install package

```
npm install chai or expect
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file chaiexpections.js and declare expect as global

```
'use strict';

// Configure chai
global.expect = require('chai').expect;
```

Now pass it in config file under cucumberopts, require

```
cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./testsuites/*.js','./chaiexpections.js','./commons/hooks.js']
    //tags: [],
    strict: true,    
    format: [],  
    'dry-run': false,           
    compiler: [],
    format: 'json:results.json',   
  },
```

This prevents the overhead of having to declare chai exception in each stepdefinition

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was importing `setupTests.ts` file inside `index.tsx` so when react app starts the development server it couldn't find the test related dependencies .

`setupTests.ts`

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

I did solve this issue the easiest way possible providing jest a config file named `jest.config.js` and removed `import "setupTests";` from `index.tsx` file .

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./src/setupTests.ts"],
};
```