# Relationship with select and checkbox angular

Tags: angularjs, select, checkbox, element

I need to select the option in select and check some values in checkbox after this.
But the problem is when I select the select option I can't check the checkbox.
I guess the problem is with the line "expect(element..."

[CODE plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jOFGKvv1rLVSt2wkRTk8)

```
$scope.isChecked = function(id, matches){
    angular.forEach(matches,function(match) {
      if(match === id){
        expect(element(by.id('check'+match)).getAttribute('checked')).toBeTrue();
      }
    });
    $scope.calculatedValue = 'You selected number ' + id +" and have "+ matches;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$scope.isChecked = function(id, matches){
angular.forEach(matches,function(match) {
  if(match.toString() === id){
        console.log(match);
    $scope.calculatedValue = 'You selected number ' + id +" and have "+ matches;
    angular.element(document.getElementById('check' + match).checked = true);
  }
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

From your plunker code I see that your `role ids` are `int` type and your select values are `string` type. And in your `if` condition you are doing a hard checking *`(=== check type and value)`*

**Solution:**

1. Either change your value types and keep them same.
2. Fix your condition.
3. Before checking cast them to be same.

Comment: I fix it, but in console this message:
ReferenceError: expect is not set
And I can not fix it.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191384/how-can-i-solve-referenceerror-expect-is-not-defined-error-message